# How to group XY data based on certain categories in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4

I'm a newbie with ArcGIS.

I have a .csv file with the boundary latitude and longitude for various polygon( or islands) and each of these polygon fall within a few categories of region. I need to generate the following file types  (for polygon) for further use - .shp, .shx, .dbf, and .prj. But before i do so i need to group these polygons based on their respective regions and this is something i have been struggling with in ArcGIS 10.4.

Comment: Can you clarify more, are you trying to add categories to a polygon layer from csv or trying to link a categorized a csv and separate polygon layer together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally was able solve the problem. Used an ArcGIS extension called Xtools Pro which provides an option for making polygons out of points by grouping on Poly Ids

Answer (score 1):

If you have a .csv file, just rename its extension to .xls or .xlsx and add data to arcmap to create its shapefile.
After doing so, you should be able to access its attribute table and use "select by attribute" where you can select the region while query or any other field you desire. Following link gives you a detail on using "select by attribute"

http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//00s500000021000000

after selection is made, you can export the data by right clicking the respective layer --> data --> export data.

This will give you the shapefiles as you described above .shp, .shx, .dbf, and .prj etc.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping Analysis is the solution, check below link :
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/grouping-analysis.htm